# Repeated classification accuracies in a loop always the same

Tags: matlab, classification, svm

I have pretty simple code for binary classification (see below). When I re-run this in Matlab (just by manually pressing the "run" button), each run gives me slightly different accuracies for each of the 14 subjects. However, if I loop over my code nrPermute times, every iteration of the loop gives me EXACTLY the same accuracy for the respective subject - why is that? So in the first code, the mean(accuracy) is different for different runs, whereas in the second code it is always the same for different iterations. Both codes below

**Code where only one 10-fold crossvalidation is done for each subject:**

```
%% SVM-Classification
nrFolds = 10; %number of folds of crossvalidation, 10 is standard
kernel = 'linear'; % 'linear', 'rbf' or 'polynomial'
C = 1; 
solver = 'L1QP';

cvFolds = crossvalind('Kfold', labels, nrFolds);

for k = 1:14

for i = 1:nrFolds                            % iteratre through each fold
    testIdx = (cvFolds == i);                % indices of test instances
    trainIdx = ~testIdx;                     % indices training instances

    % train the SVM
    cl = fitcsvm(features(trainIdx,:), 
     labels(trainIdx),'KernelFunction',kernel,'Standardize',true,...
    'BoxConstraint',C,'ClassNames',[0,1],'Solver',solver);

    [label,scores] =  predict(cl, features(testIdx,:));
    eq = sum(label==labels(testIdx));
    accuracy(i) = eq/numel(labels(testIdx));

end

crossValAcc(k) = mean(accuracy);

end
```

**Code where each 10-fold crossvalidation is repeated nrPermute times:**

```
%% SVM-Classification
nrFolds = 10; %number of folds of crossvalidation, 10 is standard
kernel = 'linear'; % 'linear', 'rbf' or 'polynomial'
C = 1; 
solver = 'L1QP';

cvFolds = crossvalind('Kfold', labels, nrFolds);
nrPermute = 5;


for k = 1:14
for p = 1:nrPermute

for i = 1:nrFolds                            % iteratre through each fold
    testIdx = (cvFolds == i);                % indices of test instances
    trainIdx = ~testIdx;                     % indices training instances

    % train the SVM
    cl = fitcsvm(features(trainIdx,:), 
     labels(trainIdx),'KernelFunction',kernel,'Standardize',true,...
    'BoxConstraint',C,'ClassNames',[0,1],'Solver',solver);

    [label,scores] =  predict(cl, features(testIdx,:));
    eq = sum(label==labels(testIdx));
    accuracy(i) = eq/numel(labels(testIdx));

end

    accSubj(p) = mean(accuracy); % accuracy of each permutation

end

crossValAcc(k) = mean(accSubj);


end
```

Answer (score 0):

In case that would be useful for someone else as well, I figure it out: The loop for permutation should be outside of cvFolds = crossvalind('Kfold', labels, nrFolds); such that the distribution into folds is re-shuffled!